# Origin of "La Belle France"?

Tags: expressions, origine-ou-raison

There's a phrase "La Belle France" used (at least in England) as a stereotypical way to refer to France.

It might be similar to (or well-known in the same as) the phrase "Merry England".

What is the origin of this phrase "La Belle France"? Is it well-known in France too (I see it's [a brand name](http://coccimarket.fr/MP_BelleFrance.aspx)) or is it mostly an English expression?

Do you know who coined the phrase or when, is it a quote from somewhere? If it is a stereotype then what (e.g. which century? town or country life?) is it a stereotype of?

Comment: France is nice... :)

Comment: It is, yes; but I'd like to know whether, when, and to whom it may be appropriate to say "La Belle France" and whether the phrase has some implicit meaning I don't know about.

Comment: "Belle France" is a trade noun, with no history ; "La Belle France" is a pamphlet and can be understood in many ways.

Answer (score 3):

Searching on google, I found [this](http://www.editionsdelondres.com/La-Belle-France) :

> « La Belle France » est un pamphlet de Georges Darien publié en 1900. C’est probablement l’un des pamphlets politiques les plus puissants et les plus violents que nous connaissions, tout là-haut avec Napoléon le petit de Victor Hugo, avec le Discours de la servitude volontaire de La Boétie. « La Belle France » n’est pas un pamphlet, c’est un exercice de tauromachie. « La Belle France », c’est la mise à mort de la Belle Epoque.

→ « La Belle France » is a lampoon of [Georges Darien](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Georges_Darien) publicated in 1900. It is probably one of the most powerful and violent politic lampoons we know, with [Napoléon le Petit](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Napol%C3%A9on_le_Petit) from [Victor Hugo](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Victor_Hugo) and with [Discours de la servitude volontaire](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discours_de_la_servitude_volontaire) from [La Boétie](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%89tienne_de_La_Bo%C3%A9tie). « La Belle France » is not a lampoon, it is a bullfighting exercise. « La Belle France » is the killing of [la Belle Epoque](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Belle_%C3%89poque).

This article, if you can read French, explain about what the text is and from where, I think, is coming the expression you describe.

We can see on [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Belle%20France&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CBelle%20France%3B%2Cc0) that this expression is existing already, but maybe not with this negative connotation. I believe G. Darien has used an already existing expression to criticize it and all what it represended.

Comment: If you think you can improve my translation, feel free to edit.

Comment: Why pick that specific pamphlet? Are you saying that the phrase is, now, because of that pamphlet, understood to be sarcastic or pejorative?

Comment: Le premier lien est très riche en explications :)

Comment: @ChrisW : Darien wasn't the first to use the phrase. His use is ironical and personal and if people use it (if it used at all outside travel guides) it is used just for what it means. I gather it is more of a phrase in English as it is in French!

Comment: @ChrisW I pick this lampoon (=/= pamphlet in English but = pamphlet in French) because its name *is* « La Belle France ». G. Darien wasn't the first to use this calling, and won't be the last for sure, but his lampoon is a pretty good first publication underlining how this expression can have a sarcastic and corrosive meaning. Did you understand what was written in [the link](http://www.editionsdelondres.com/La-Belle-France)? It is very interesting for you imho.

Comment: @Laure The usage of the expression by G. Darien may be personal as you say, but ChrisW describes a common usage in English nowadays. I don't clame it was the first use ever, because it is very hard to distinguish the ironical from the classic usage. But « La Belle France » is a lampoon about France and is highly criticizing how *beau*tiful it tries to appear during his epoch.

Comment: `Did you understand...?` Oui merci, je sais lire ce qui y est écrit. Mais ce que je ne comprenais pas, c'est pourquoi vous me l'avez donné comme réponse. Il me semble que l’auteur a choisi ce titre afin de se moquer d’une expression déjà courante. Et donc ce pamphlet  ne peut être l’origine de cette expression. Mais peut être que vous me le donnez, comme exemple d’un sens ironique de cette phrase. Si on employait cette phrase aujourd’hui, dites-vous que ce serait surtout (ou, qu'il serait entendu surtout, ou seulement) dans un contexte ironique et non sincère ?

Comment: @ChrisW I didn't want to be offensive, it was just a question to be sure my answer helped you (which is not the case if you can't read easily French). As I commented in your answer, the usage you ask in your question *is* ironical and not litteral.

Comment: Référence à : _La Belle Époque_ +1. Merci.

Answer (score 3):

> Is it well-known in France too (I see it's a brand name) or is it mostly an English expression?

The brand name is anecdotal with probably a close to zero average level of recognition.

*La Belle France* is mostly an English expression, notwithstanding that would be *La belle France* in French (unless it is a title), it is not commonly used here, especially with the stereotypical meaning you describe.

On the other hand, a pretty close well known French expression is :

> Elle est belle, la France !

It is typically used in an ironical way by French people while complaining about some unpleasant fact about France.

It is well possible *La Belle France* was coined from *Elle est belle, la France*.

Comment: [Informations about this *dislocation*.](http://www.projet-voltaire.fr/blog/actualite/la-france-elle-est-effet-de-style-ou-faute-de-francais) (Don't mind the political argument)

Answer (score 1):

A more careful search with ngram finds [the phrase being used by Jean de La Fontaine](https://books.google.fr/books?id=8oBdAAAAcAAJ&dq=%22la%20belle%20france%22&pg=PT1017#v=onepage&q=%22la%20belle%20france%22&f=false) (1621–1695) ... I'm not saying he invented the phrase, maybe it was a commonplace in speech even in his time.

Comment: You have to decide if you want the origin of the sarcastic idiom, or the origin of people calling their country beautiful

Comment: I wanted the origin of the idiom; I had no premonition that the idiom was ever used sarcastically.

Comment: But, the usage you described is sarcastical. The litteral meaning is *The Beautiful France*.

Comment: @Divulgâchâmes "Merry England" probably implies feasting and music, in the feudal ages. I was wondering whether "Belle France" suggests anything specific, like milk-maids and geese, or the cafe life, or the Age of Enlightenment, or etc.?

Comment: `Imho, there is no way for someone who is not privy to this to know beforehand it refers to the stereotype.` Yes and that's why I was asking: given that it is an idiomatic compound phrase, is there some stereotypical meaning associated with it?

Comment: @Divulgâchâmes You don't have any reason, do you, for saying that it was coined in English?

Comment: Using Google (which I'm not sure is a good test) I do seem to find it more on English-language web pages than on French-language.